# Unresolved reference during build when extending Java class from Kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I have an Android project that compiles just fine when it comes to Java classes, however when I tried to rewrite one of these classes to Kotlin I got **unresolved reference** error and cannot build the project anymore.

**The class2 extends class1**

The project structure is as follow:

```
/src
../com
..../package
....../app
......../Class1.java
......../Class2.kt
```

`Class1.java` declares the package `com.package.app` and same thing for the `Class2.kt`. For an obvious reason Android Studio complains about **Package does not correspond to file path** on the Java file but surprisingly does not complain about it in the Kotlin file.

As I mentioned above when Class2 was written in Java, I had the Package does not correspond error but that doesn't prevent me from building my apk. Now that I'm trying to use Kotlin I cannot build anymore.

I tried to set the source on my gradle file but it didn't help.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile  'AndroidManifest.xml'
        kotlin.srcDir "src/com/package/app/"
        kotlin.setIncludes(new HashSet(['Class1.java']))
    }
}
```

The same config with Java works perfectly (given that kotlin.* is replaced by java.*)

While doing some research I found this [topic](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/root-package-declaration-to-reduce-folder-clutter/2247) that somehow is close to my issue but unfortunately it doesn't describe how to fix it.

Also important to note that Android studio is able to reference the extended class correctly.

Comment: Java classes must be in the correct directory for their package. Kotlin classes do not.

Comment: How come there is no issue when using only Java? Is there any place(gradle?) where I can manually set a path for a class?